# unable to setup pyspark in windows 10 even after setting system/environment variables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i have set the system variables as required yet spark-shell doesn't launch, i have tried to set all in system variables and not in environment/user variables.

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
HADOOP_HOME = E:\Arun\Software\hadoop
SPARK_HOME = E:\Arun\Software\Spark\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7
path = %HADOOP_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

[image: variable details]

Comment: Ьaybe close the console and open the new or restart PC? It looks correct.

Comment: @JDev i did try restart as well, its just not working